# Loop em PHP para criar array com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php

quero prencher um array com dados vindo do banco de dados com PHP e MySQL, o array está sendo preenchido, mas não no formato que seria mais funcional para a aplicação. 
Alguma dica para mudança no loop para chegar ao formato idel do array?

**Este é o formato ideal para a aplicação:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => survey
    [1] => processing
    [2] => factoring
    [3] => closed
    [4] => developing
)
```

**Loop para criar o array:**

```
public function fillArrayPrStatus() {
        try {   
            $this->conn = parent::getConnection();
            $this->pQuery = $this->conn->prepare(   'select status_pr_status '.
                                                    'from pr_status '.
                                                    'where   status_pr_lang=:sessionLanguage'
                                                );
            $this->pQuery->execute(array(   ':sessionLanguage' => session::sessionLanguage()    ));
            if($this->pQuery->errorCode() == 0) {
                $this->get_rows = $this->pQuery->fetchAll();
                foreach($this->get_rows as $this->get_row)  {
                    $this->arrayPrStatus[] = $this->get_row;    
                }   
                return; 
            }   
            else     {
                throw new Exception();
            }   
        }   
        catch (Exception $e)    {
            $tException = new tException();
            $tException -> newException($e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e->getTraceAsString());
        }   
    }
```

**Resultado após o loop:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status_pr_status] => processing
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status_pr_status] => closed
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status_pr_status] => developing
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [status_pr_status] => survey
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [status_pr_status] => factoring
        )

)
```

Comment: Eu acho que `$this->get_row` já é um array, certo? Dê-me um exemplo do formato deste, faça print a um deles

Comment: Miguel.. $this->get_row está definida como array, mas sem valor definido, uso esta variável somente em loops. Assim como a variável $this->arrayPrStatus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente na linha onde insere o novo valor no array, dentro do foreach:

```
...
$this->arrayPrStatus[] = $this->get_row['status_pr_status'];
...
```

Comment: Miguel... Valeu.. agora está certo. <br>                                                Array
(
    [0] => processing
    [1] => closed
    [2] => developing
    [3] => survey
    [4] => factoring
)

Comment: hehe de nada @RRV